Clang error: libdnk.a, libunwind.a and libc++.a linkage issues in windows build
I am trying to build an ELF file using the ARM-M4 toolchain version 8.1.0. My C code files compile successfully, but I encounter the following error while linking the object files
[100%] Linking C executable ../test/bin/my_App.elf
ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: time
>>> referenced by clock.c
>>>               clock.c.o:(clock) in archive C:\compiler\toolchains\arm\v8.1.0\arm\lib/v7-m/thumb/vfpv4/hard/dp_d16/except\libdnk.a
>>> referenced by tzset.c
>>>               tzset.c.o:(tzset) in archive C:\compiler\toolchains\arm\v8.1.0\arm\lib/v7-m/thumb/vfpv4/hard/dp_d16/except\libdnk.a
>>> did you mean: ctime

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: __exidx_start
>>> referenced by libunwind.cpp
>>>               libunwind.cpp.o:(__unw_init_local) in archive C:\compiler\toolchains\arm\v8.1.0\arm\lib/v7-m/thumb\libunwind.a
>>> referenced by libunwind.cpp
>>>               libunwind.cpp.o:(libunwind::UnwindCursor<libunwind::LocalAddressSpace, libunwind::Registers_arm>::setInfoBasedOnIPRegister(bool)) in archive C:\compiler\toolchains\arm\v8.1.0\arm\lib/v7-m/thumb\libunwind.a

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: gettimeofday(timeval*, timezone*)
>>> referenced by chrono.cpp
>>>               chrono.cpp.o:(std::__1::chrono::system_clock::now()) in archive C:\compiler\toolchains\arm\v8.1.0\arm\lib/v7-m/thumb/vfpv4/hard/dp_d16/except\libc++.a

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: getentropy
>>> referenced by random.cpp
>>>               random.cpp.o:(std::__1::random_device::operator()()) in archive C:\compiler\toolchains\arm\v8.1.0\arm\lib/v7-m/thumb/vfpv4/hard/dp_d16/except\libc++.a

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I am using Arm M4 architecture and below are the my compiler flags
TOOLCHAIN ==>> "C:\compiler\toolchains\arm\v8.1.0\arm\include"

set(COMMON_CFLAGS 
    --target=armv7m-none-eabi
    -march=armv7-m
    -mcpu=cortex-m4
    -mfpu=vfpv4-d16
    -mlittle-endian
    -std=gnu99
    -g3
    -Wextra
    -Wall
    -I${TOOLCHAIN}
    -ffunction-sections
    -fdata-sections
)

target_compile_options(${TEST_EXECUTABLE} PUBLIC ${COMMON_CFLAGS})

set(LOCAL_LDFLAGS
    -T${MY_LINKER_FILE}
    -Wl,-Map,${TEST}/${TEST_EXECUTABLE}.map
    -Xlinker 
    --allow-multiple-definition 
    -Xlinker 
    -mfpu=vfpv4-d16
    -march=armv7-m
    -mfloat-abi=hard
    -mthumb
)

target_link_options(${TEST_EXECUTABLE} PUBLIC ${LOCAL_LDFLAGS})

I don't know why these errors are coming when we build .c files. I am new to cross compiling. Why libc++.a required for linking .c files?  Initially I thought , I am missing .a files during linkage. So I have added these files in the LD flags like below
TOOLCHAIN_LIB ==> "C:\compiler\toolchains\arm\v8.1.0\arm\lib\v7-m\thumb"

-mfloat-abi=hard
    -mthumb
    -I${TOOLCHAIN_LIB}/vfpv4/hard/sp_d16/libclang_rt.builtins.a
    -I${TOOLCHAIN_LIB}/vfpv4/hard/sp_d16/except/libdnk.a
    -I${TOOLCHAIN_LIB}/libunwind.a
    -I${TOOLCHAIN_LIB}/vfpv4/hard/sp_d16/except/libc++.a
    -I${TOOLCHAIN_LIB}/vfpv4/hard/sp_d16/except/libc++abi.a


I can also see .a files in the toolchain folder like above. However, even after adding these files, I am still encountering the same error. Has anyone else faced similar issues, or is there a workaround to resolve these errors?

Please add a [mre] to your question.

Probably the library you lack is not libc++.a but libc.a. The functions time() and gettimeofday() are part of the standard C library.  You are using libraries that are written in C++, so it is normal that you need also the standard c++ library.
